# Planning to buy some cat5e cables. 568A or 568b?

Tags: networking, cable, cat5e

I plan to buy about 20-30 feet of Cat5e (or 6) cables. I have 30 mbits connection. I was looking around and the ones we are considering are 568B. I was looking for quality in my cables. Is this appropriate?

If they're no good, what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

568B is a termination standard and has nothing to do with the cable itself.  568A is an alternate termination standard and not as widely used.  Both perform equally the thing is you need to choose one and stick to it at a particular instalation so as to avoid confusion later on.

Comment: Well put. In addition, it's useful to know that a crossover cable has one end wired by each standard. Not that crossover cables are needed that much any more - the vast majority of NICs out there support auto MDX.